# definition of level in mixed models

Tags: mixed-model

What exactly constitutes a "level" in mixed models? In most texts I have read levels seem to be synonym with random variables (student ID, classroom, school, etc). But can predictors also be levels? For example, if I'm interested in math scores, family income, and IQ, can I say these are levels nested within students?

As an example consider this data set:

```
df = data.frame(ID=rep(c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6"),each=4), scores=floor(runif(24, min=0, max=100)), age=rep(c(14,17,14,16,18,12),each=4), test=rep(c(1,2),times=12), day=rep(c("day1","day2"),each=2,times=6),school=rep(c("A","B"),each=12))
```

I'd read it as `school` as the upper level (level 1), then pupil `ID` nested within schools (level 2), then `day` nested within pupil ID? (level 3), then `test` nested within day (level 4). Is that correct? What about `age`, can that be considered a separate level as well?

Answer (score 0):

They are synonymous with variables, whether they are random or fixed depends on the data and the problem. See chapter 9 of https://bookdown.org/steve_midway/DAR/random-effects.html
for example. The nature of the variable determines how you model them.